# A Generic Compare Function , With A Variable Condition

Tags: c, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to use the function

```
List listFilter(List list , CompareFunction func);
```

which , as you all well know , returns a filtered list according to a specific condition , from a given list; the param list .

Here's the definition of CompareFunc :

```
typedef int (*CompareFunc)(ListElement);
```

ListElement is of course void* .

I'm currently working on a problem in which a ListElement is an object that stores information regarding a person , whereas the information includes their age .

I'm trying to write a function which groups a given list of people based on their age, which can obviously vary, therefor I'm trying to write a function which compares a ListElement against an int , i.e a person's age against an age category , respectively , suppose it's defined thusly :

```
bool ageIsValid(ListElement person , int ageCategory);
```

and pass it down as a parameter to listFilter .
However, the problem that I've encountered is that CompareFunc's definition is not decided by me , i.e , I'm the user of the ADT List , so I can't pass ageIsValid directly to listFilter.

Is there an available solution which doesn't rely on global variables ? , since it's frowned upon in this specific course that I'm currently taking .

All answers would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT :

I just had an idea , and I was wondering if it'd work :

I'll define a static function like so :

```
    static List listFilterCustom(List list , int age){
        static bool filterByAge(ListElement element){
            /* pAge = getAgeOfPerson(element); */
            return pAge == age;
        }
        return listFilter(list , filterByAge);
     }
```

i.e , I'll define a function inside the scope of listFilterCustom , in which the variable age is recognized , thus excluding the use of global variables .
Is this solution valid ?

Comment: Is it correct to assume *neither* the prototype for CompareFunc (which really should be called FilterFunc since it only takes one param) ***nor*** the `listFilter()` API are modifiable?

Comment: Yes , that is correct , the implementation was provided by the faculty for optional use .

Comment: then you're somewhat up a creek without a paddle, and I'd throttle the author of that API with prejudice. I see no immediate way you're going to do this without an external element of some kind. In *theory* you could have a prime-able static in a comparison function that took a special `ListElement` your function "knows" is *not* part of the list, and sets its filtering static data from that element. You would then "set" the filter data by invoking the function with your "filter-state" prior to invoking `listFilter`, but such a solution would be brittle at-best.

Comment: I've considered this solution , by it involves defined another struct specifically designed to hold this form of information , but I've already defined a number of data types . Please see my recent edit suggesting another solution .

Comment: You cannot nest functions in C.

Comment: Maybe redefine as inline ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify `listFilter`; e.g. to accept an additional parameter with an opaque pointer:

```
List listFilter(List list, CompareFunction func, void *info);
```

`CompareFunction` must be modified accordingly to accept this `void *` pointer.

You can than pass additional information in this parameter (e.g. `&wanted_age_category`) and cast it back in your comperator.

Comment: That would solve my predicament , except that I cannot do so , as was explicitly specified in my description :) .